# Ordering and ranking variables across multiple columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame with numerous variables and trying to assign a ranked value to each variable after sorting by the variable itself and then a control variable. I am able to do this on a variable by variable basis, but unsure how to automate this across n number of desired variables. Below is how I am performing the task on a variable by variable basis:

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = 1:16)
df$VarA <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,14,NA_real_,NA_real_,NA_real_,16)
df$VarB <- c(10,0,0,0,12,12,12,12,0,14,NA_real_,14,16,16,16,16)
df$VarC <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df$VarD <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df$ControlVar <- c(1,2,4,6,1,2,4,6,1,2,4,8,1,2,7,6)

df %>%
  arrange(VarA,ControlVar) %>%
  mutate(VarA_pos = row_number()) %>%
  arrange(VarB,ControlVar) %>%
  mutate(VarB_pos = row_number()) %>%
  arrange(VarC,ControlVar) %>%
  mutate(VarC_pos = row_number()) 

   ID VarA VarB VarC VarD ControlVar VarA_pos VarB_pos VarC_pos
1   9    1    0   10   10          1        3        1        1
2   1    1   10   10   10          1        1        5        2
3   5    1   12   10   10          1        2        6        3
4  13   NA   16   10   10          1       14       12        4
5   2    1    0   12   12          2        4        2        5
6   6    1   12   12   12          2        5        7        6
7  10    1   14   12   12          2        6       10        7
8  14   NA   16   12   12          2       15       13        8
9   3    1    0   14   14          4        7        3        9
10  7    1   12   14   14          4        8        8       10
11 11    1   NA   14   14          4        9       16       11
12 15   NA   16   14   14          7       16       15       12
13  4    1    0   16   16          6       10        4       13
14  8    1   12   16   16          6       11        9       14
15 16   16   16   16   16          6       13       14       15
16 12   14   14   16   16          8       12       11       16
```

I tried using the lapply function, but it generated 4 lists with the exact same output (see below).

```
lapply(Var_names, function(x) {
  df %>% arrange(x, ControlVar) %>% mutate(Var_Pos = row_number())
}) 

[[1]]
   ID VarA VarB VarC VarD ControlVar Var_pos
1   1    1   10   10   10          1       1
2   5    1   12   10   10          1       2
3   9    1    0   10   10          1       3
4  13   NA   16   10   10          1       4
5   2    1    0   12   12          2       5
6   6    1   12   12   12          2       6
7  10    1   14   12   12          2       7
8  14   NA   16   12   12          2       8
9   3    1    0   14   14          4       9
10  7    1   12   14   14          4      10
11 11    1   NA   14   14          4      11
12  4    1    0   16   16          6      12
13  8    1   12   16   16          6      13
14 16   16   16   16   16          6      14
15 15   NA   16   14   14          7      15
16 12   14   14   16   16          8      16

[[2]]
   ID VarA VarB VarC VarD ControlVar Var_pos
1   1    1   10   10   10          1       1
2   5    1   12   10   10          1       2
3   9    1    0   10   10          1       3
4  13   NA   16   10   10          1       4
5   2    1    0   12   12          2       5
6   6    1   12   12   12          2       6
7  10    1   14   12   12          2       7
8  14   NA   16   12   12          2       8
9   3    1    0   14   14          4       9
10  7    1   12   14   14          4      10
11 11    1   NA   14   14          4      11
12  4    1    0   16   16          6      12
13  8    1   12   16   16          6      13
14 16   16   16   16   16          6      14
15 15   NA   16   14   14          7      15
16 12   14   14   16   16          8      16

[[3]]
   ID VarA VarB VarC VarD ControlVar Var_pos
1   1    1   10   10   10          1       1
2   5    1   12   10   10          1       2
3   9    1    0   10   10          1       3
4  13   NA   16   10   10          1       4
5   2    1    0   12   12          2       5
6   6    1   12   12   12          2       6
7  10    1   14   12   12          2       7
8  14   NA   16   12   12          2       8
9   3    1    0   14   14          4       9
10  7    1   12   14   14          4      10
11 11    1   NA   14   14          4      11
12  4    1    0   16   16          6      12
13  8    1   12   16   16          6      13
14 16   16   16   16   16          6      14
15 15   NA   16   14   14          7      15
16 12   14   14   16   16          8      16

[[4]]
   ID VarA VarB VarC VarD ControlVar Var_pos
1   1    1   10   10   10          1       1
2   5    1   12   10   10          1       2
3   9    1    0   10   10          1       3
4  13   NA   16   10   10          1       4
5   2    1    0   12   12          2       5
6   6    1   12   12   12          2       6
7  10    1   14   12   12          2       7
8  14   NA   16   12   12          2       8
9   3    1    0   14   14          4       9
10  7    1   12   14   14          4      10
11 11    1   NA   14   14          4      11
12  4    1    0   16   16          6      12
13  8    1   12   16   16          6      13
14 16   16   16   16   16          6      14
15 15   NA   16   14   14          7      15
16 12   14   14   16   16          8      16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should get what you want by using `rank` with `ties.method = "random"` which will ensure that you get unique values for each row. We can use `across` to apply this to multiple columns and assign appropriate names to new columns.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(ControlVar) %>%
  mutate(across(VarA:VarC, rank, ties.method = "random", .names = '{col}_pos'))

#   ID VarA VarB VarC VarD ControlVar VarA_pos VarB_pos VarC_pos
#1   1    1   10   10   10          1        5        5        4
#2   5    1   12   10   10          1        4        8        2
#3   9    1    0   10   10          1       11        4        3
#4  13   NA   16   10   10          1       14       14        1
#5   2    1    0   12   12          2        6        3        5
#6   6    1   12   12   12          2        7        6        8
#7  10    1   14   12   12          2        9       11        6
#8  14   NA   16   12   12          2       15       13        7
#9   3    1    0   14   14          4        2        1       12
#10  7    1   12   14   14          4        3        9       11
#11 11    1   NA   14   14          4        1       16        9
#12  4    1    0   16   16          6       10        2       14
#13  8    1   12   16   16          6        8        7       16
#14 16   16   16   16   16          6       13       15       13
#15 15   NA   16   14   14          7       16       12       10
#16 12   14   14   16   16          8       12       10       15
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, unfortunately this isn't a solution as I need to sort by a variable (e.g. VarA) and the Control variable (ControlVar) then assign a rank, then do this again for the next variable (VarB) and the Control variable (ControlVar) then assign a rank, and so on. Thats why I was trying to loop it as the sort (i.e. arrange function) changes for each variable

Comment: I know and I think `rank, ties.method = "random"` does the same thing. Compare the output of your manual way with my answer. The only difference is when there is a tie the number might change within themselves but overall rank is properly assigned.

Comment: Thanks Ronak, you are right! I changed ties.method = "first" and this gave me the order  based on the Control_Var which is what I need. Thanks again